# Java charset encoding

Tags: java, encoding, nio

According to this documentation, there are two different canonical names that character encodings have depending on which page you use : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html

> The following tables show the encoding sets supported by Java SE 7.
>   The canonical names used by the new java.nio APIs are in many cases
>   not the same as those used in the java.io and java.lang APIs.

So it's my understanding that if I create a new inputstream and specify the NIO canonical name, then it will work, but is there a way to identify the charset using both the java.nio package, and then use that charset with the java.io package.

So an example would be, I have a charset that java.io doesn't recognize, I would then check for it in java.nio, and if it's found, I would somehow pass that to the regular io inputstream.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the NIO charset classes `Charset`, `CharsetEncoder`, and `CharsetDecoder` with the java.io classes [`OutputStreamWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html#OutputStreamWriter%28java.io.OutputStream,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) and [`InputStreamReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29).

Note that the only thing you gain by doing this is access to user-defined or third party charset implementations in the java.io API.